# Binding embedded List of objects on a Thymeleaf template for a POST request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am developing a grocery store list web application. One feature should be (un)checking found/bought items on the list. Displaying all the values works fine. But when I check some checkboxes on some bought items and try to POST it afterwards the incomming `@ModelAttribute` in the spring MVC controller is null (except the id).

I hope you can help me.

Here are my classes:

```
public class PurchaseList {

private Long id;
private List<PurchaseItem> purchaseItemList;
private DateTime purchaseDate;
private boolean done;
}


public class PurchaseItem {

private Long id;
private String purchaseItemName;
private PurchaseCategory purchaseCategory;
private PurchaseList purchaseList;
private boolean found;
}
```

The Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)  
public String postPurchaseList(@PathVariable(value="id") Long id, @ModelAttribute("purchaseList") PurchaseList purchaseList, Model model) {
  List<PurchaseList> notDonePurchaseList = purchaseListService.getNotDonePurchaseList();
  model.addAttribute("notDonePurchases", notDonePurchaseList);
  purchaseListService.savePurchaseList(purchaseList);
  return "purchaseList";
}
```

The Thymeleaf template

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/purchaseList/{purchaseListId}/(purchaseListId=${purchaseList.id})}" th:object="${purchaseList}" method="post">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Found</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Category</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr th:each="item,status : ${purchaseList.purchaseItemList}">
          <td><input type="checkbox" th:checked="${item.found}" th:value="*{purchaseItemList[__${status.index}__].found}" /></td>
          <td th:text="${item.purchaseItemName}"></td>
          <td th:text="${item.purchaseCategory.categoryName}"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
      </form>
```

I know that I doesn't set the other values (only the `found` property). Or is this the problem?

Best regards

**Edit:**

1. Initialized as suggested the `ArrayList` purchaseItemList. Now an empty `ArrayList` is returned to the controller.

Comment: can you show us the controller?

Comment: Of course. Just edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the purchaseItemList in PurchaseList class.

    `public class PurchaseList {
    private Long id;
    private List<PurchaseItem> purchaseItemList=new ArrayList<>();
    private DateTime purchaseDate;
    private boolean done;
    }`

Give a input field an id like this.

`<td><input type="checkbox" th:checked="${item.found}" th:value="*     {purchaseItemList[__${status.index}__].found}" th:id='purchaseList.purchaseItemList[__${status.index}__].found'/></td>`

Comment: This leads to that i got an empty ArrayList returned to my controller. Maybe it's a step forward

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem and the solution.

I've seen in some tutorials and blog posts the usage of `th:field=*{..}` but I didn't use it, because i trusted the Spring Tool Suite (it doesn't offer the `th:field` attribute on autocomplete. Therefore I was sure that this attribute couldn't be used anymore. But I was wrong. I changed in my template code some of the `*th:value=${..}` attributes to `th:field=*{..}` as follows:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/purchaseList/{purchaseListId}/(purchaseListId=${purchaseList.id})}" th:object="${purchaseList}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
  <input type="hidden" th:field="*{purchaseDate}" />
  <input type="hidden" th:field="*{done}" />
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Found</td>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Category</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr th:each="item,status : ${purchaseList.purchaseItemList}">
      <td><input type="checkbox" th:checked="${item.found}" th:field="*{purchaseItemList[__${status.index}__].found}" th:id="${'purchaseList.purchaseItemList[__${status.index}__].found' + 'status.index'}"/></td>
      <td th:text="${purchaseList.purchaseItemList[__${status.index}__].purchaseItemName}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{purchaseItemList[__${status.index}__].purchaseItemName}" 
        th:value="${purchaseList.purchaseItemList[__${status.index}__].purchaseItemName}"
        th:id="${'purchaseList.purchaseItemList[__${status.index}__].purchaseItemName'}"
        />
      </td>
      <td th:text="${item.purchaseCategory.categoryName}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{purchaseItemList[__${status.index}__].purchaseCategory.categoryName}" 
        th:value="${purchaseList.purchaseItemList[__${status.index}__].purchaseCategory.categoryName}"
        th:id="${'purchaseList.purchaseItemList[__${status.index}__].purchaseCategory.categoryName'}"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
  </form>
```

Now it works better. I get the "found" attributes in the controller. The other values are not set. But I think I messed up something within the hidden input fields.